# How to calculate common elements in a dataframe depending on another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this.

```
sport      Country(s)
Foot_ball    brazil
Foot_ball    UK
Volleyball   UK 
Volleyball   South_Africa
Volleyball   brazil
Rugger       UK 
Rugger       South_africa
Rugger       Australia
Carrom       UK
Carrom       Australia
Chess        UK
Chess        Australia
```

I want to calculate the number of sports shared by two countries. For a example

Football and  Volleyball is common  to  brazil and Uk. So the number of common sports played  by brazil and Uk is 2.

carrom, chess and Rugger are common to australia and Uk. So the number of sports shared by australia and UK is 3.

Like this is there anyway that I can get a count in whole dataframe for
       brazil, south_afriaca.
       Brazil, Austrlia
       SouthAfrica, Uk
       e.t.c

Can anybody suggest me how to do this in pandas or any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pd.factorize` and `itertools.combinations`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations, product

# Fix Capitalization
df['Country(s)'] = ['_'.join(map(str.title, x.split('_'))) for x in df['Country(s)']]

c0, c1 = zip(*[(a, b)
               for s, c in df.groupby('sport')['Country(s)']
               for a, b in combinations(c, 2)])

i, r = pd.factorize(c0)
j, c = pd.factorize(c1)
n, m = len(r), len(c)
o = np.zeros((n, m), np.int64)
np.add.at(o, (i, j), 1)

result = pd.DataFrame(o, r, c)
result

              Australia  Uk  South_Africa  Brazil
Uk                    3   0             2       1
Brazil                0   1             0       0
South_Africa          1   0             0       1
```

Make symmetrical

```
result = result.align(result.T, fill_value=0)[0]
result

              Australia  Brazil  South_Africa  Uk
Australia             0       0             0   0
Brazil                0       0             0   1
South_Africa          1       1             0   0
Uk                    3       1             2   0
```

---

#### `pd.crosstab`

This will be slower... almost certainly.

```
c0, c1 = map(pd.Series, zip(*[(a, b)
   for s, c in df.groupby('sport')['Country(s)']
   for a, b in combinations(c, 2)]))

pd.crosstab(c0, c1).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1).pipe(
    lambda d: d.align(d.T, fill_value=0)[0]
)

              Australia  Brazil  South_Africa  Uk
Australia             0       0             0   0
Brazil                0       0             0   1
South_Africa          1       1             0   0
Uk                    3       1             2   0
```

Or including all sports within a single country

```
c0, c1 = map(pd.Series, zip(*[(a, b)
   for s, c in df.groupby('sport')['Country(s)']
   for a, b in product(c, c)]))

pd.crosstab(c0, c1).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)

              Australia  Brazil  South_Africa  Uk
Australia             3       0             1   3
Brazil                0       2             1   2
South_Africa          1       1             2   2
Uk                    3       2             2   5
```

Comment: is there a way that we can get Australia also into the first column and makes the number of rows and columns equal?

Comment: perfect.Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't Australia have 3 sports in common with Australia for example? Mean in the diagonal I would expect to have the number of sports that country has.

Comment: That's a good question.  I assumed not to show "in common with self"  BUT I should've asked.  @bob do you want Australia to have 3 sports in common with Australia?

Answer (score 3):

With the sample data you provided you can generate the desired output with below code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
[["Foot_ball", "brazil"],\
["Foot_ball", "UK"],\
["Volleyball", "UK"],\
["Volleyball", "South_Africa"],\
["Volleyball", "brazil"],\
["Rugger", "UK"],\
["Rugger", "South_Africa"],\
["Rugger", "Australia"],\
["Carrom", "UK"],\
["Carrom", "Australia"],\
["Chess", "UK"],\
["Chess", "Australia"]],\
columns = ["sport" , "Country"])

# Function to get the number of sports in common
def countCommonSports(row):
    sports1 = df["sport"][df["Country"]==row["Country 1"]]
    sports2 = df["sport"][df["Country"]==row["Country 2"]]
    return len(list(set(sports1).intersection(sports2)))

# Generate the combinations of countries from original Dataframe
from itertools import combinations
comb = combinations(df["Country"].unique(), 2)
out = pd.DataFrame(list(comb), columns=["Country 1", "Country 2"])

# Find out the sports in common between coutries
out["common Sports count"] = out.apply(countCommonSports, axis = 1)
```

output is then:

```
>>> out
      Country 1     Country 2  common Sports count
0        brazil            UK                    2
1        brazil  South_Africa                    1
2        brazil     Australia                    0
3            UK  South_Africa                    2
4            UK     Australia                    3
5  South_Africa     Australia                    1
```

Comment: Note: I changed "South_africa" for "South_Africa" (capitalized Africa) in the original data provided by the OP.